# hyperref TextField extends into margin

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, forms

Whenever the line would have to break right before the TextField, it doesn't and instead lets the TextField run off the page.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\TextField[width=12cm]{very long text explaining the type of entry that should go here:}\\

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the label text is simply printed at after it the box. You would get the same with normal text and e.g. a picture. You could e.g. use a parbox:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\TextField[width=12cm]{\parbox[t]{5cm}{very long text explaining the type of entry that should go here:}}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Or redefine `\LayoutTextField`.

Comment: I tried out some stuff as well and adding \newline at the end of the label text also works (might not be very clean though). I was wondering whether there was an automatic solution, but either of these two does the job.

Comment: no there is nothing automatic. It is not really possible to guess which behaviour is wanted here (a break at a fix width, or a newline or ....). So the default definition of `\LayoutTextField` is very simple. But as I wrote you can adapt it.